# Stream.io Chat API - Using Stream Chat with Observables / RxJS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, getstream-io

The Node version of the docs for Stream's Chat API use `async/await` to connect to the Stream Chat service via the JS client. [I have read the RxJS docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) on connecting to Websockets, which is what I understand the Stream Chat client is doing under the hood. 
My question is how I produce `Observables` from Stream Chat events? For example, from the event object such as this one:

```
channel.on('message.deleted', event => {
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('channel.state', channel.state);
});
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Let me know if my answer is good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a socket like connection you can wrap it with an Observable like this

```
function channelObs(channel) {
    return new Observable<any>(
        (subscriber: Observer<any>) => {
            channel.on('eventId', 
                event => {
                    subscriber.next(event);
                }
            );
            return () => {// tearDownLogic, i.e. code executed when this Observable is unsubscribed
        }
    );
}
```

The Observable returned by the function `channelObs` can be treated with all operators offered by RxJS

Answer (score 0):

You need create a `Subject` and subscribe it as follows

**chat.service.ts**

```
private chatEventListener = new Subject<any>();

bindEvents(){
   channel.on('message.deleted', event => {
    const eventObj = {
       event : event,
       state : channel.state
    };
    this.chatEventListener.next(eventObj );
  });
}

subscribeToNotifications(){
  this.chatEventListener.asObservable();
}
```

in **component.ts**

```
this.chatService.subscribeToNotifications().subscribe(event => {
   console.log(event);
})
```